# Django Rest Framework, passing attributes in the url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have this 2 models:

```
class ProductQualityMonitor(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(..)
    area = models.CharField(...))
    timeslot = models.DateTimeField(...)

    def get_measured_parameters(self):
        (...)

class QualityParameter(models.Model):
    PARAMETER_CHOICES = (
        (MEAN, MEAN),
        (MEDIAN, MEDIAN),
        (MAXIMUM, MAXIMUM),
        (MINIMUM, MINIMUM),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PARAMETER_CHOICES)
    value = models.FloatField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductQualityMonitor,
                                related_name="parameters")
```

I need to get some aggregate stats about the quality parameters. I have a method that receives some attributes, like the date range, and aggregates the stats ten by ten for each parameter, and at the end returns a json object with all the aggregate stats.

My doubt is: can I call this method, passing the parameters that the method needs in the url, and see the results? And, if i can, how do I do it?

Sorry if my explanation is a little messy, I am new in Django.

Answer (score 8):

Two ways I did to pass attributes from URL for Django REST framework:

### 1. From URL path

Sample URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/passthisstringfrompath

In urls.py (with the assumption that the attribute is a string):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myurl/<str:myattribute1>/', MyRestApiView.as_view()),
]
```

In views.py:

```
class MyRestApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("myattribute1", None) is not None:
            print("the passed attribute:", kwargs["myattribute1"]) # this should print "passthisstringfrompath"
        return Response()
    def post(self):
        pass
```

The parameter *args and **kwargs are the Python way of passing undefined number of list (*args) and dict (**kwargs) objects, something like Args... in C++, more info [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). This is used because in class based views, URL parameters are fetched from this kwargs, more info [here](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/working-with-url-get-post-parameters-in-django/).

### 2. From URL query parameters

Sample URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/?myattribute1=passthisstringfromparam

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myurl/', MyRestApiView.as_view()),
]
```

In views.py:

```
class MyRestApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.GET.get("myattribute1", None) is not None:
            print("the passed attribute:", request.GET["myattribute1"]) # this should print "passthisstringfromparam"
        return Response()
    def post(self):
        pass
```

Or better yet just use "*query_params*" as advised in documentation for Django under https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/ by literally substituting all instances of "*request.GET*" to "*request.query_params*" and then everything else the same.

### Additional info

Of course you can combine both ways above to support URLs that are a combination of both such as: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/passthisstring/?mynextattribute=thenthissecond&mylastattribute=andthenthislast

Where:

- kwargs["myattribute1"] = "passthisstring"
- request.query_params["mynextattribute"] = "thenthissecond"
- request.query_params["mylastattribute"] = "andthenthislast"

Beware of the order of urlpatterns to not mix one with another, always put more specific ones at front of the list:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myurl/<str:myattribute1>/', MyRestApiView.as_view()),
    path('myurl/', MyRestApiView.as_view()),
]
```

Or better yet, you could also simplify this urlpatterns into a single pattern which takes into account the case when the input attribute is optional:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('myurl/(?:(?P<myattribute1>\w+)/?)?', MyRestApiView.as_view()),
]
```

Just beware of the trailing slash / at the end so that the following URLs would lead to the same resource:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/passthisstring
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl/passthisstring/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `GET` parameters in your URL and retrieve them in your view

```
your.url.com?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Then in your view

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class YourView(APIView):


    def get(self,request):
        parameters = request.query_params
        #use your URL parameters
```

Comment: Sorry by the silly question but... how do i define the url in the url.py? Because url(r'^test/$', views.YourView.as_view()), doesn't work.

Comment: you don't need to specify url parameters in your `urls.py` if you are passing them via  GET using `?` . Try this `url(r'^test/$', views.YourView.as_view({'get':'get'})) `

Comment: I have this view, like you said:  
  
class YourView(APIView):  
        def get(self,request):  
            parameters = request.data  
            return Response(parameters)  
  
And the url: url(r'^test/$', views.YourView.as_view())  
  
And then i call: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/?param1=Euro, but the response appears empty. I tried your last suggestion, but gives a error

Comment: I solved the problem, i put request.query_params instead of request.data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SaraTomaz yep, i forgot, for  query parameters is query_params. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters in the GET url

## Viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets

class YourViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(YourViewset, self).get_queryset()
        id = self.request.query_params.get('id', None)
        # do some operations return queryset
```